# How do I set up my raspberry pi so that I can connect to its ip address via a domain

Tags: raspberry-pi, ip, http, domain

Let me explain what I want to happen.

I have an http server program that displays a website every time I connect to my raspberry pi's ip address on port 8080. But this only works on my current network. I want to be able to access this raspberry pi from any network by typing a website address. How would I connect my URL to this raspberry pi so that I can just type the domain and it will take me to my raspberry pi?

P.S. I have already tried searching for this extensively, but none of the results fits my needs

Thank you in advance,

Nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your raspberry pi is probably located in your local network behind a router/firewall/modem.

You should let your router to forward connections from outside to your raspberry pi. It depends if you want IPv4 or IPv6 or both. You should then make a DNS entry for your public IP address. https://no-ip.com/, for instance,  offers free DNS. If you have a static IP, you can just enter that IP. If you have dynamic IP, you can get a program for your raspberry pi, which would update DNS record when your IP changes.

This is just a short description, of what needs to be done. To make everything detailed it would take more than one answer here. You should start and ask separate questions for each task.